# $a^m=b^m$ and $a^n=b^n$ imply $a=b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $D$ be an integral domain and let $a^m=b^m$ and $a^n=b^n$ where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers, $a,b \in D$.

How do I show $a=b$?

Comment: Hint: If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $mx + ny = 1$.

Comment: Can you show this in the special case where $m = n+1$?

Comment: Subhint: let $D$ the set of $k$ such that $a^k=b^k$. You know that $n$ and $m$ are in $D$ and you want to show that $1$ is in $D$. What other integers do you know as being in $D$?

Comment: Sorry: not your $D$...

Comment: maybe you could use this identity : (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7473/15660)

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105633/prove-that-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-elements-of-the-integral-domain-d) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/105633).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No generality is lost by supposing $m < n$.  So $a^n=b^n$ implies $a^{m+(n-m)}=b^{m+(n-m)}$, or $a^ma^{n-m}=b^mb^{n-m}$.  In integral domains, there's a cancellation property, so $a^{n-m}=b^{n-m}$.

The pair $(m,n)$ has now been replaced by the pair $(m,n-m)$.  If you iterate that process, replacing the pair you've got with the pair consisting of the larger of the two and the difference---the larger minus the smaller, that's [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).  It ends when you reach the gcd.

Comment: Here the integral domain doesn't have a unit.
Will the cancellation property still hold?

Comment: @user Suppose $xy = xz$ with $x \ne 0$. Then $x(y-z)=0$; by the definition of an integral domain, since $x \ne 0$, it must be the case that $y - z = 0$.

Comment: @user774025 It's been a while since I've thought these issues through, but I've just look in Herstein's undergraduate text, _Topics in Algebra_, and he gives a definition of _integral domain_ that doesn't assume that those have a unit, and in that context proves that every integral domain is embedded in a field of quotients.  If it's embedded in a field of quotients, then it must have the cancellation property.

Answer (score 7):

I came across a similar problem but with the condition that $m$ and $n$ are positive coprime integers. The following is my solution.

If $a=0$, then $b^m=a^m=0$. It follows that $b=0=a$ since $D$ is an integral domain.

If $a \ne 0$, since gcd(m,n)=1, $\exists s, t\in \mathbb z $ such that $1=sm+tn$. Because $ m, n>1$, $s,t \in \mathbb z$ and $1 = sm + tn$, we have either $s>0, t<0$ or $t>0, s<0$ (Otherwise we cannot have $1=sm+tn$).

Let's assume $s>0, t<0$. Then $-t>0$. From $a^m = b^m$, we have $(a^m)^s=(b^m)^s$. From $a^n=b^n$, we have $(a^n)^{-t}=(b^n)^{-t}$. We can factor out as follows.

$$a^{-tn}(a^{sm+tn})=b^{-tn}(b^{sm+tn})$$

$$a^{-tn}(a^{sm+tn})=a^{-tn}(b^{sm+tn})$$
$a^{-tn} \ne 0$ since $a \ne 0$ and $a$ is in an integral domain. We can cancel $a^{-tn}$ on both sides.Then we get $a^{sm+tn}=b^{sm+tn}$, i.e. $a^1=b^1$.

The proof for the case where $s<0, t>0$ is similar.

Comment: Nice approach! +1

Answer (score 3):

Since $m$ and $n$ are coprime then $x m - y n=1$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb Z$. The equality $a^m=b^m$ implies that $a^{xm}=b^{xm}$ so $a^{1+yn}=b^{1+yn}$
which implies that : $$(*)\;\;\;  \;a a^{yn}=b b^{yn}$$ 
Since $a^{n}= b^{n}$ then $a^{yn}=b^{yn}\not = 0$ so we can cancel $a^{yn}$ and $b^{yn}$ from both sides of $(*)$ since we are working in an integral domain, and then we get $a=b$.

Comment: What if $y \lt 0$? then the expression $ a^{yn}$ will be meaningless?

Comment: It has meaning in the quotient field of the domain $D$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ The set $\,S\,$ of naturals $\,k>0\,$ with $\,a^{\large k} = b^{\large k}\,$ is nonempty & closed under positive subtraction, i.e. $\, j>k \in S\,\Rightarrow\,j-k\in S\,$ (by cancelling $\,a^{\large k} = b^{\large k}\,$ from $a^{\large j} = b^{\large j}).$ Thus a [fundamental lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/664094/242) implies the least element $\,\ell\in S\,$ divides every element of $\,S.\,$ In particular, $\,\ell\,$ is a common divisor of the coprimes $\,m,n\in S,\,$ thus $\,\ell = 1.\,$ Hence $\,1\in S,\,$ i.e. $\, a = b.\ \ $ **QED**

Answer (score 0):

Let $a^m = b^m$ $\rightarrow$ Implies that: 
$$O(a)=m \text{ and } O(b)=n \tag{1}$$

Let $a^m = b^m$ $\rightarrow$ Implies that:
$$O(a)=n \text{ and } O(b)=n  \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2)
$$O(a) = m = n \text{ and } O(b) = m = n$$
$\rightarrow$
Implies that:   $a^{m=n} = b^{m=n}$

Which is $a^{(m|n)} = b^{(m|n)}$ by relatively prime

Implies that $a^1 = b^1$

Hence proved which is $a = b$.

Comment: Please use MathJax formatting

Answer (score -2):

What's the necessity of $D$ to be a domain?
As $(m,n) = 1$ we have two integers $x$ and $y$ such that $mx+ny = 1$

so, $a^{mx} = b^{mx}$ and $a^{ny} = b^{ny}$ which implies, $a^{mx+ny} = b^{mx+ny} = a = b$

Comment: Your proof only works if $x,y$ are both positive.

Comment: Can you elaborate @MartinBrandenburg? I have the same proof and I am struggling to understand what’s wrong with it.