# If $a$ and $b$ are elements in a ring with $a^n=b^n$ and $a^m=b^m$ then $a=b$

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I was doing the first exercises from the book **Exercises in Basic Ring Theory** by *G. Călugărescu* and *P. Hamburg* and I found one whose solution isn't quite clear to me.

> **Ex. 1.4** If $a$, $b$ are elements in a ring $R$ and $n$, $m$ $\in \mathbb{N}^*$, $(n;m)=\text{gcd}(n,m)=1$ are such that $a^n=b^n$ and
>   $a^m=b^m$ then $a=b$.
>
> **Solution:** If $(n;m)=1$ there are integers $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $sn+tm=1$. But then
>   $a=a^1=a^{sn+tn}=(a^n)^s·(a^m)^t=(b^n)^s·(b^m)^t=b^{sn+tm}=b^1=b$.

Now, in the book they don't consider rings to be integral domains; indeed they don't even consider rings to be commutative. So, since $s$ or $t$ might be negative, how can be justified the step $a^{sn+tn}=(a^n)^s·(a^m)^t$?

Comment: You need _some_ sort of assumption either on $a$ and $b$ or on $R$, otherwise this is not true. Consider the case where $a$ and $b$ are two different, nilpotent elements.

Comment: Looks to me that the statement is false, consider $x,y \in \Bbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$, then $x^k = y^k = 0$ for all $k>1$ but $x \ne y$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1821622/589 shows how to avoid negative  exponents but not the requirement to be a domain.

Comment: Indeed exactly one of $s$ or $t$ is negative, which may cause troubles, as we don't know whether the ring is a field and hence an element might not have an multiplicative inverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true if the ring does not have divisor of zero.

Suppose that $m<n$, write $n=pm+r$, you have $a^n=a^{pm+r}=b^{pm+r}=b^{pm}b^r=a^{pm}b^r$. You deduce that $a^{pm}a^r=a^{pm}b^r$ and $a^{pm}(a^r-b^r)$ and $a^r=b^r$.

Thus the assertion is true for $(m,r)$ you can repeat this process until the rest is 1.