# Is "a and b being relatively prime" the only situation where na+mb=1 for some n,m?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose a and b are two integers such that gcd(a, b)=1.

First, is there any simple argument showing why there must be some integers $n$, $m$ such that $na+mb=1$?

Second, is this the sufficient condition for us to say there exist $m$ and $n$ such that $na+mb=1$?

Thank you!

Comment: For both questions, yes. See [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/664094/242) for a conceptual proof of Bezout's identity for the gcd. It is sufficient since if $\,na+mb = 1\,$ then $\,d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid na+mb = 1,\,$ so $\,\gcd(a,b) = 1.\,$