# $ax\equiv b\pmod{\! n}$ has a unique solution if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{\! n}\,$ has a unique solution if $\,\gcd(a,n) = 1$?

I suspect that the Bezout identity for $\,\gcd(a,b) = 1$ is the key but I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: Notice that $\gcd(a,p)=1$ and use Bezout's Identity and quotient remainder theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Bezout plays a key role, see below.

**Theorem** $\ $ The following are equivalent for integers $\rm\:c,\, m.$

$(1)\rm\ \ \ gcd(c,m) = 1$
$(2)\rm\ \ \ c\:$ is invertible $\rm\,(mod\ m)$
$(3)\rm\ \ \ x\to cx+d\:$ is $\:1$-$1\:$ $\rm\,(mod\ m)$
$(4)\rm\ \ \ x\to cx+d\:$ is onto $\rm\,(mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\  (1\Rightarrow 2)\  $ By [Bezout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout's_identity) $\rm\, gcd(c,m)\! =\! 1\Rightarrow cd\!+\!km =\! 1\,$ for $\rm\,d,k\in\Bbb Z\,$ $\rm\Rightarrow cd\equiv 1\!\pmod{\! m}$
$(2\Rightarrow 3)\ \ \ \rm cx\!+\!d \equiv cy\!+\!d\,\Rightarrow\,c(x\!-\!y)\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,x\!-\!y\equiv 0\,$ by multiplying by $\rm\,c^{-1}$
$(3\Rightarrow 4)\ \  $ Every $1$-$1$ function on a finite set is onto (pigeonhole).
$(4\Rightarrow 1)\ \ \ \rm x\to cx\,$ is onto, so $\rm\,cd\equiv 1,\,$ some $\rm\,d,\,$ i.e. $\rm\, cd+km = 1,\,$ some $\rm\,k,\,$ so $\rm\gcd(c,m)=1$

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/664094/242) for a conceptual proof of said Bezout identity for the gcd.