# How do I prove Bézout's identity of polynomials in $F[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

$F$ is a field.
$a(x),b(x)\in F[X]- F$.
$\gcd(a(x),b(x)) = d(x)$ and $u(x)a(x)+v(x)b(x)=d(x)$.

I need to prove that: $\deg(u)<\deg(b)-\deg(d)$.
I use the fact that degree is replacing the absolute value, but I still stuck...

Can you give a hint please? Or what is the direction of the proof?

Thank you!!

Comment: You use the division algorithm. *Exactly* the same way you prove it in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *proof* is essentially the same [as for integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/664094/242) -  descent via (euclidean) division with remainder. To compute the Bezout identity for $\,\gcd(f,g,h)\,$ note that
the set $I$ of polynomials of the form $\, a f + b g +ch$ is closed under addition and scaling so it is closed under remainder = mod, since that is a composition of such operations: $f_i\bmod g_i = f_i - q\, g_i. $ It follows that the $\rm\color{#c00}{least}$ degree $d\in I$ divides every  $e\in I\,$ (else $0\neq e\bmod d\,$ is in $\, I\,$ but has $\rm\color{#c00}{smaller}$ degree than $d).\,$

So $\,f,g,h\in I\Rightarrow d\,$ is a *common* divisor of $\,f,g,h\,$ necessarily a *greatest* (degree) common divisor by $\, d'\mid f,g,h\,\Rightarrow\, d'\mid d\!=\! \bar a f + \bar b g+\bar ch,\,$ so $\,\deg d'\le \deg d.\,$ To force the gcd $\,d\,$ to be unique the common convention is  scale it [to be *monic*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3009888/242) (lead coef $=1).\,$

The [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124307/242) is an efficient way to search  $I$ for a polynomial of minimal degree, while  keeping track of each element's representation as a linear combination of $\,f\,$ and $\,g.$

The same idea works for any *Euclidean domain* (i.e. enjoying division with (smaller) remainder).

---

We show there exists a Bezout identity with the sought $\rm\color{#c00}{degree\ bound}$ on the coefficient $\,\color{#c00}u\,$  of $\,a.\,$ By above there is a Bezout identity $\ u' a + v'b = d.\,$  Dividing $\,u'\,$ by $\,b/d\,$ yields $\,u' = q\, b/d + u\,$ with quotient $\,q\,$ and remainder $\, u\,$ satisyfing the sought  $\,\color{#c00}{\deg(u) <} \deg(b/d) = \deg(b)-\deg(d)$

Substituting $\,u' = q\, b/d + u\,$ into $\ d = u'a + v'b \ $ yields the sought Bezout identity, i.e.

$$ d = u'a+v'b = (q\, b/d + u)\,a + v'b = u\,a + (\color{#0a0}{v' + q\,a/d})\, b = \color{#c00}u\,a+\color{#0a0}v\,b \qquad\qquad  $$

It's clearer via mod: $\ 1 = u' a/d + v' b/d\iff u'\equiv (a/d)^{-1}\!\pmod {\!b/d}$ and any such inverse $u'$ remains an inverse when reduced $\!\bmod b/d\,$ to $\, u:= u' \bmod b/d = $ the remainder above. So the algebra above amounts to modular reducing an inverse to force its degree less than the modulus.

Comment: What is $c$ at your answer? Thank you!

Comment: @CS1 There $\ c\mid f,g,\,$ i.e. $\,c\,$ is any common divisor of $\,f,g\,$ (we are aiming to show that every common divisor $c$ divides $d,\,$ hence $d$ is a *greatest* common divisor). $\ \ $

Comment: What is $f$ here?

Comment: OK, I'm waiting... :-)

Comment: You right! I mix the letters, sorry: this is the right one: $\deg(u) < \deg(b) - \deg(d)$

Comment: I deleted them! Thank you so much! You help me a lot!!

Comment: @CS1 Ok, I'm back and I added a simpler approach to my answer (it's equivalent to what I wrote before but doesn't require knowing the prior-linked result).

Comment: Thank you!! Can you explain me please the first line of your edit? I don't understand it...

Comment: @CS1 Please say more precisely where you are stuck. The idea is simply that if $\,u,v\,$ are Bezout coef's then so too are $\bar u,\, \bar v$ where $\bar u$ has the sought minimal degree.

Comment: I stuck here: $\,\bar u = u\bmod b/d = u\!-\! q\,b/d,\,$ can explain this? how did you get it?

Comment: Divide $\,u\,$ by $\,b/d\,$ to get $\ u = q\, b/d + \bar u,\ $ with remainder $\, \bar u = u\bmod b/d\,$ of degree $< \deg(b/d)\ \ $

Comment: So $\bar u$ is the reminder? (the same $u$ at $ua+vb=d$?)

Comment: @CS1 It's not clear what you mean by "same as".

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain better: We know that $ua+vb=d$ so the $u$ is equal to: $\ u = q\, b/d + \bar u$? And if yes, how exactly?

Comment: @CS1 No, as said above we divide $\,u\,$ by $\,b/d\,$ to get the remainder $\,\bar u,\,$ i.e. $\, \bar u = u\bmod (b/d)\ \ $

Comment: OK! I think I understand... But how you get it from: $ua+vb=d$?  you divide it by $d$ not by $\frac{d}{b}$ (I think I miss something here...)

Comment: @CS1 We don't use the Bezout identity to do the division. We use division with remainder to write $\, u = \bar u + q\, b/d\,$ then use that to substitute for $\,u\,$ in the Bezout identity to reformulate it in terms of $\bar u\ \ $

Comment: So - how do you get this $u = \bar u + q\, b/d$ and $v$ is the same thing but with $a$? i.e. $u = \bar u + q\, b/d$ is by definition or something else? Thank you!!

Comment: @CS1 Please point to a specific location in the answer where you are stuck.

Comment: OK - first of all $\bar u = u\bmod b/d = u\!-\! q\,b/d$ - you define it? because when I try to find the connection to $ua+vb=d$ and I don't understand how to connect it...

Comment: And other thing: about - $\,\deg(\bar u) < \deg(b/d) = \deg b - \deg d$, it should be $\,\deg(u) < \deg(b/d) = \deg b - \deg d$, so how I convert the $\deg(\bar u)$ to $u$?

Comment: The proof shows that given any Bezout identity we can transform it into one where the coef of $\,a\,$ has the sought degree (via $\, u\to \bar u\,$ as above).

Comment: So I think that what I missed is how do you make this transform... This is what I don't understand...

Comment: Maybe be problem is due to the fact that the problem is misstated. It should say that there *exists* some $u$ satisfying the degree bound. Is that clear?

Comment: I'm not sure because this is what I need to prove...But you right - I think that " there exists some u satisfying the degree bound." as you write describes it well... But I still don't understand the connection between $\bar u$ and what I need to prove.. :-( When I what you wrote - I see the proof, but it's feels like the are some steps that are "missing" for me...

Comment: @CS1 What I call $\bar u\,$ is the minimal $\,u\,$ that you seek. What I call $\,u\,$ you can call something else, e.g. $\,u_0\,$ to get the notation you seek.

Comment: OK, I'll try to understand if I will have any questions I'll ask you here (I think there is some mess at my head :))

Comment: I still don't understand this: $\bar u = u\bmod b/d = u\!-\! q\,b/d$ it's something you define? how do you get this? If you can explain more it will be excellent!!

Comment: @CS1 By the *polynomial division algorithm* we can divide $\,u\,$ by $\,b/d\,$ to get $\, u = q\, b/d + r\,$ with quotient $\,q\,$ and remainder $\,r,\ $ where $\, \deg r < \deg b/d.\ $  We define $\,\bar u\,$ as the remainder $\,r,\ $  which can also be written as $\, \bar u = u\bmod b/d\ \ $

Comment: But this is the same $u$ as at the $ua$?

Comment: @CS1 The proof in the answer shows that there exists some Bezout identity $\, u\,a + v\,b = d.\,$  We transform that into $\, \bar u \,a + \bar v\, b = d\,$ to get a Bezout identity with the required degree bound on the coeff of $a\ \ $

Comment: So if I understand right you are doing "zoom-in" to $u$ at the $ua$ and call it $\bar u$ - and then you bound it? (bound the degree).

Comment: @CS1 I rewrote the 2nd half of the answer. Maybe it will be clearer to you  now.

Comment: It's much more clear now, thank you! So you decided to to divide it by $b/d$ to get the wanted result?

Comment: @CS1 Yes, the above proof shows that if $\,u'$  is a Bezout coeff for $\,a\,$ then so to is $\, u := u'+q\,b/d\,$ for *any* $\,q.\,$ We simply chose $q$ so that it leads to the lowest possible degree for $\,u,\,$ which occurs when $\,q\,$ is said quotient, so $\,u\,$ is the remainder $= u'\bmod b/d\ \ $

Comment: It would be useful to collect the information from the many comments and incorporate them into the answer. Comments are not for extended discussions.

Comment: I read it few times and try to understand - but at your last comment you decided to divide it ($\bar u$) by $b/d$  to get the wanted result - I was wondering - you can divide it by ANYTHING and you can get any bound you want... What I miss here?

Comment: @CS1 $\,b/d\,$ works because $(b/d)a = (a/d)b  = {\rm lcm}(a,b)\,$ is a common multiple of $\,a,b\,$ which allows us to move the summand $\,(q\,b/d)a\,$ from $\,u'a\,$  into a summand $\,(q\,a/d)b\,$ in $\,v\,b.\,$ Being the *least* common multiple it's the least degree polynomial with this property. The second approach I gave using $\!\bmod\,$ yields a more intuitive viewpoint.